# What are the main approaches allowing to efficiently simulate quantum circuits, and which hypotheses those circuits have to fulfill

Tags: quantum-algorithms, simulation

In general, it is very computationally intensive to simulate the evolution of a quantum system. However, in some particular cases, an efficient classical simulation of a quantum algorithm is possible.

One example is the case of stabilizer circuits. For algorithms in which the initial quantum state is a computational state, if all the gates of the algorithm are in the Clifford group and if all the measurements are performed in the computational basis, it is possible to simulate the evolution of the quantum algorithm with a classical computer with $O(n \times N)$ classical operations, where $n$ is the number of qubits and $N$ the number of quantum gates used in the algorithm. [Ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406196)

I am also aware of tensor-network-based simulations of entangled circuits. Here the exact hypotheses required differ, but to give an example, in some specific cases, if the entanglement doesn't grow "too quickly" with the size of the computation, it is possible to efficiently follow the wavefunction along the algorithm using some tools from tensor-networks theory. A few examples can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511070) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301063).

### My question

I would like to have some good references for the main approaches that allow for an efficient (i.e. polynomial-time as a function of the variable of interest) simulation of quantum circuits. **I am interested both in pure and mixed-state computation**.

1. What are the "most important" methods that allow simulating efficiently specific quantum circuits? Are the tensor network technique and the stabilizer formalism the two main categories? Are there other approaches that can be used?
2. (Related) Which "ingredients" are required to make all those methods "fail" to follow the evolution. I know that in pure state quantum computing, entanglement must grow with the size of the computation and that Clifford *and* non-Clifford gates are required for instance (at least if preparation and measurements are in the computational basis). Are there other general ingredients known?

For (2) the question might be complicated to answer as I guess there might have too many conditions to fulfill. It depends on how we decide to "split" the ingredients. But if there are some interesting things to say here I am interested to hear about them.

Comment: Matchgate circuits.

Comment: A very partial answer: for efficient simulation of stabilizer circuits (aka circuits that produce positive Wigner functions), see chapter 4 of this thesis: https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/7699/Veitch_Victor.pdf.